# How to call jquery functions from Swift?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, swift, xcode

The following code is how to call `Javascript` functions from `Swift`

```
        if let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jssrc", ofType: "js"){
        do {
            let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)
            self.jsContext.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I thought I could do something similar for `jquery`.  I have an identical codeblock to the one above, the only difference is I specify the official `jquery` library to evaluate.

I get the following error when I try to evaluate `jquery.js`, however.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.createElement')
```

Why is `document.createElement` resolving to `undefined`?  Do I need to modify the class `jsContext` is a member of, such that the view is a `WKWebView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Document](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) refers to document object model or DOM. Since your Swift view is not a web page there is no DOM so this is why its undefined. I think you can call Javascript functions from Swift but once the Javascript function relies on the DOM and manipulating HTML in the DOM I think this is where you will have issues in Swift.